# Running debug server with bundle exec in aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana, bundler, radrails

I'm trying to debug a rails application, but when I've tried, it throws me :

```
Uncaught exception: You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

Obviously this in a terminal is really easy, but I don't know if I could change this on Aptana. Is there a way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this problem, too. I've made a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179081/how-do-i-use-bundle-exec-in-aptana-studio-3-0-9-to-run-the-debugger But haven't had any results.