# How do I use bundle exec in Aptana Studio 3.0.9 to run the debugger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, shell, rvm, zsh

Aptana seems to start in the `sh` shell. So I'm trying to switch to `zsh`, and execute commands to start a rails app.

I've changed my debug executable so that it runs a unix executable with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
exec("zsh | (echo $SHELL && [[ -s '$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm' ]] && source '$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm' && rvm use 1.8.7@tinderbox && (bundle exec script/server -p3001 &))")
```

So, when I click my debug executable from the debug menu on the toolbar, the debug perspective appears, and it shows that

```
myApp [Ruby Application]    
    Ruby    
    /usr/bin/ruby
```

is running and hasn't been terminated.
but when I go to my browser and type in 0.0.0.0:3001, I get "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3001" - which means that the server sin't running.

I have the output of the executable set to a file on my desktop here is what happens every run:

```
 Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.4) listens on 127.0.0.1:55306
/bin/zsh
```

- Note: I get the same results with bash as with zsh

What is going on? and how do I get my command to work?

Answer (score 1):

type

```
zsh -l
```

and in new zsh shell:

```
rvm 1.8.7 do bundle exec script/server -p3001
```

or with rvm wrapper:

generate wrapper for bundle:

```
rvm wrapper 1.8.7 run bundle
```

it will generate `run_bundle`, find it:

```
which run_bundle
```

and use it in aptana:

```
/path/to/run_bundle exec script/server -p3001
```

Comment: I need to do this all in one line, because I'm trying to get Aptana Studio 3 to use bundle exec to run my rails server so I can actually debug it, and not worry about printing everything when I want to debug =D

Comment: I don't know anything about wrappers, but the problem is that the executables need to be in the project directory.

Comment: I can not understand, does it mean that you are limited to programs that are on PATH. and can not use /full/path/to/project ? this seams as a silly limitation, why someone would do that.

Comment: A lot of IDEs do that. Because everything in your project should be relative to your project, so it can be easily transported between machines.